# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, As a beginner Android Development is really difficult but i will never give up

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, As a beginner, Android Development is really difficult but I will never give up

While creating My application I phase many problems at the end everything was going good
Then, I connected my phone start Debugging my app
Hence the error came down

Error line:

Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Log Here:

```
2021-07-08 21:27:55.682 701-18184/? I/netd: networkCreatePhysical(1945, 2) <34.03ms>
2021-07-08 21:27:55.683 701-18184/? I/netd: createNetworkCache(1945) <0.05ms>
2021-07-08 21:27:55.683 1409-1686/? E/OppoConnectivityService: oppo_sla:setOppoSlaIfaceUp:warning...slaIface=ccmni0 slaIpaddr=null slaDns=null
2021-07-08 21:27:55.683 1409-1686/? D/MtkConnectivityService: Adding iface ccmni0 to network 1945
2021-07-08 21:27:55.684 701-18184/? E/Netd: interface ccmni0 already assigned to netId 636
2021-07-08 21:27:55.684 701-18184/? I/netd: networkAddInterface(1945, "ccmni0") -> ServiceSpecificException(16, "Device or resource busy") <0.05ms>
2021-07-08 21:27:55.684 1409-1686/? E/MtkConnectivityService: Exception adding interface: java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: Device or resource busy (code 16)
2021-07-08 21:27:55.685 701-18184/? I/netd: interfaceSetMtu("ccmni0", 1500) <0.19ms>
2021-07-08 21:27:55.685 701-18184/? E/Netd: interface ccmni0 assigned to netId 636, not 1945
2021-07-08 21:27:55.685 701-18184/? I/netd: networkAddRoute(1945, "ccmni0", "::/0", "") -> ServiceSpecificException(2, "No such file or directory") <0.04ms>
2021-07-08 21:27:55.686 1409-1686/? E/NetworkManagement: Connector Failed to execute cmd 
    android.os.ServiceSpecificException: No such file or directory (code 2)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2101)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2055)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2003)
        at android.net.INetd$Stub$Proxy.networkAddRoute(INetd.java:3025)
        at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.modifyRoute(NetworkManagementService.java:997)
        at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.addRoute(NetworkManagementService.java:962)
        at com.android.server.MtkConnectivityService.updateRoutes(MtkConnectivityService.java:6190)
        at com.android.server.MtkConnectivityService.updateLinkProperties(MtkConnectivityService.java:6072)
        at com.android.server.MtkConnectivityService.updateNetworkInfo(MtkConnectivityService.java:7242)
        at com.android.server.MtkConnectivityService.handleRegisterNetworkAgent(MtkConnectivityService.java:6043)
        at com.android.server.MtkConnectivityService.access$4600(MtkConnectivityService.java:276)
        at com.android.server.MtkConnectivityService$InternalHandler.handleMessage(MtkConnectivityService.java:4222)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2021-07-08 21:27:55.686 701-18184/? E/Netd: interface ccmni0 assigned to netId 636, not 1945
2021-07-08 21:27:55.686 701-18184/? I/netd: networkAddRoute(1945, "ccmni0", "2401:4900:42c8:f6eb::/64", "") -> ServiceSpecificException(2, "No such file or directory") <0.06ms>
2021-07-08 21:27:55.687 1409-1686/? E/NetworkManagement: Connector Failed to execute cmd 
    android.os.ServiceSpecificException: No such file or directory (code 2)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2101)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2055)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2003)
        at android.net.INetd$Stub$Proxy.networkAddRoute(INetd.java:3025)
        at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.modifyRoute(NetworkManagementService.java:997)
        at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.addRoute(NetworkManagementService.java:962)
        at com.android.server.MtkConnectivityService.updateRoutes(MtkConnectivityService.java:6190)
        at com.android.server.MtkConnectivityService.updateLinkProperties(MtkConnectivityService.java:6072)
        at com.android.server.MtkConnectivityService.updateNetworkInfo(MtkConnectivityService.java:7242)
        at com.android.server.MtkConnectivityService.handleRegisterNetworkAgent(MtkConnectivityService.java:6043)
        at com.android.server.MtkConnectivityService.access$4600(MtkConnectivityService.java:276)
        at com.android.server.MtkConnectivityService$InternalHandler.handleMessage(MtkConnectivityService.java:4222)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Thank you for your Help In Advanced

Comment: "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs" -- for compile-time problems, the log in question is the build log from your IDE, not the Logcat logs from the device.

Comment: @CommonsWare how can I get log you need...??